# Objective C, declard nsstring by "if statement"

Tags: objective-c

New in OBJ-c,
Im tring to set a varible with some if statement and it's not work.

```
if (_imageView,image==NULL) { 
     NSString *isFileSet = @"NOFILE";
}
else 
{
     NSString *isFileSet = @"FILESET";
}
NSLog(@"%@",isFileSet);
```

and I cant run the project, I get an err: "Use of undeclared identifier "isFileSet".
what is worng here ?

Comment: What do you think the comma is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you declared the variables in the `if` block. The variable won't exist outside of it (true for all programming languages I can think of). You should have declared it outside:

```
NSString *isFileSet;
if (_imageView.image==NULL) { 
    isFileSet = @"NOFILE";
}
else 
{
    isFileSet = @"FILESET";
}
NSLog(@"%@",isFileSet);
```

You should have also fixed the if-statement.

Comment: The comma should be a dot

Comment: @MikelPascual Thanks, that's what I thought but wondered if that was something I didn't know about.